# Problems with image adaptive resizing + Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, resize

Good evening to all!!

I'm facing some problems with image resizing & Javascript.

I wrote a function to resize an image maintaining aspect ratio.
Here's the function:

```
function computeRatio () {

        var el_image = document.getElementById("div_image");

        var newImg = new Image();           
        newImg.src = document.getElementById("image").src;

// GET IMAGE REAL DIMENSIONS

        var image_height = newImg.height;
        var image_width = newImg.width;

// SET WINDOW DIMENSIONS

        var window_height = 762;
        var window_width  = 600;

// COMPUTE DIMENSION RATIOS

        var height_ratio  = image_height / window_height;
        var width_ratio   = image_width / window_width;

// RESET IMAGE POSITION

        el_image.style.left = "0px";
        el_image.style.top = "0px";

        if (height_ratio > width_ratio) {
            var width = window_height/(image_height/image_width);

// SET NEW DIMENSIONS (MAX HEIGHT & NEW WIDTH)

            el_image.style.width  = width+"px";
            el_image.style.height = window_height+"px"

// SET NEW POSITION TO CENTER IMAGE

            var scroll_x = (window_width-width)/2;

            el_image.style.left = scroll_x+"px";

        } else {
            var height = window_width*(image_height/image_width);


// SET NEW DIMENSIONS (MAX WIDTH & NEW HEIGHT)

            el_image.style.width  = window_width+"px"
            el_image.style.height = height+"px";

            var scroll_y = (window_height-height)/2;

            el_image.style.top = scroll_y+"px";
        }

}
```

This is the relevant part in HTML:

```
<div id="div_image" style="display: block;">
    <img src="" alt="0" id="image" onLoad="computeRatio ()"/>
</div>
```

It works really fine except when handling a not-so-small image (i.e size > 1MB).

When this occours, the function computes the correct dimensions, but then the image is displayed in full screen (W=600px, H=762px) and, obviously, it isn't centered!

I really can't understand why this happens!!

Any help?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain aspect ratio for an image in a container, just set the image to `display:block` and add a `width:100%`. The effect is that the image will fill the to the width of the containing element, and height will automatically adjust.

```
#image {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```